# c# IHTMLDocument2 set the URL property

Tags: c#

I need to create a complete IHTMLDocument2 document so I end up with this snippet which works. However, the URL property seems to be ignored all the times.

string page = "my HTML code in string";

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = (IHTMLDocument2)new HTMLDocument();
doc2.url = "www.stackoverflow.com"; 
doc2.write(new object[] { page });
doc2.close();

while (doc2.body == null)
    Application.DoEvents();
```

Now doc2.url is always "about:blank". How can I set this URL property?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Uppsss... there is a website that clones stackoverflow questions immediately: http://answers.elteacher.info/questions/post/677321/c-ihtmldocument2-set-the-url-property-ask-question.html